# Android Studio - Why is R randomly becoming Red?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-resources

This has happened on a few different occasions, and I've always just kind of ignored it - but now I'm getting close to being finished with some of my projects, so it can no longer be ignored..

**The Issue is as follows**:  While working on a project in Android Studio, on multiple occasions, seemingly at random, references to "R" will become Red, as if it were an error (or not found)..

For example, in my Main Activity, this reference to R is red, indicating an Error.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

}
```

Everything with Android Studio is updated via the standard update channel.. The project isn't complicated whatsoever, and I haven't messed with anything that could be delicate, or somehow affect R.. so I'm left extremely confused..

**Can anybody offer any kind of explanation regarding this issue?**
I would greatly appreciate any advice I can get :) Thanks!


**UPDATE:** ALTHOUGH THE "DUPLICATE" I WAS LINKED TO BELOW (WHICH I READ FOR ABOUT AN HOUR) DID IN FACT CONTAIN SOME GOOD INFORMATION, IT WAS HOWEVER, A CONVERSATION THAT SEEMED TO CIRCULATE AROUND ECLIPSE (RATHER THAN ANDROID STUDIO, WHICH COULD DRASTICALLY CHANGE THINGS IN SOME CASES). THAT SAID, I DID FINALLY SUCCESSFULLY FIX THE CAUSE OF THE ISSUE! THIS PARTICULAR CASE WASN'T DIRECTLY REFERENCED IN THE LINK I WAS GIVEN, ALTHOUGH I DID GATHER ENOUGH FROM IT TO KNOW GENERALLY WHERE TO SNOOP AROUND FOR THE ERROR. SURE ENOUGH, IT WAS ACTUALLY A MANIFEST FILE REFERENCE TO THE APP ICON (LOL) SOMEHOW IT WAS MESSING THINGS UP, AND SO IN THE 
`<APPLICATION>` SECTION OF THE MANIFEST FILE, I SIMPLY HAD TO ADD:

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

AFTER THAT, I WENT TO THE MENU AND DID A REBUILD, AND FINALLY IT BUILT THE PROJECT SUCCESSFULLY WITHOUT ANY ERRORS! HOPEFULLY THIS HELPS SOMEBODY ELSE OUT THERE WITH THE SAME ISSUE! 
..FOR THOSE OF YOU WHO WANT THE SHORT VERSION OF WHAT I READ IN THE LINK: IN GENERAL, THE "R" NOT FOUND ISSUE SEEMS TO BE CAUSED MOSTLY BY ERRORS OR MISTAKES WITHIN ONE OF YOUR XML RESOURCE FILES WHICH CAUSES R TO NOT BUILD PROPERLY. THANKS FOR THE LINK.

Comment: Any layout file or resource you edit will affect R. If you have some error in your XML, R cant be created

Answer (score 0):

The R file is a generated file, so you need to build the program in order to get the references to it. Make sure you check this answer to see how to rebuild it :

> Android studio is based on Intellij Idea. In Intellij Idea you have to do the following from the GUI menu.

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```